# I have developed a web application with DotNet core 5.0 after BUILD I have deployed .DLL Files into IIS Server but I am getting below error

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dll

An error occurred while starting the application.
InvalidOperationException: Application is running inside IIS process but is not configured to use IIS server.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISServerSetupFilter+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)

InvalidOperationException: Application is running inside IIS process but is not configured to use IIS server.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISServerSetupFilter+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter+<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
Boom_API.Program.Main(string[] args)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `webBuilder.UseKestrel()` from host builder and try

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
       Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
           .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
           {
               webBuilder.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
               webBuilder.UseIISIntegration();
               webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
           });
```